# Custom Matrix product

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a list:

```
list1 = {{{a1, a2, a3}, {b1, b2, b3}}, {{c1, c2, c3}, {d1, d2, d3}}};
```

[image: my list]

I want an operation that gives me:

[image: what I want]

Is there a built-in way of doing this? Basically, this is meant to be the `ImageData` of a picture and I want to double the resolution by increasing the number of pixels and doing further operations on it. I tried

```
KroneckerProduct[list1, {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}]
```

but it didn't give me what I wanted.

If there is no built-in method of doing this, what is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Btw, I tried copying the matrix entries here, but neither the mathML nor the Latex worked. they all appeared in a way different to the way they show in Mathematica.

Comment: Welcome,you are repeating your list elements so just club them as {list1,list1,list1,list1} , `Flatten` than Sort than `Split` them. Try once it shall do. Also try to include code while posting.

Comment: @Blackbird Thanks. But sorting it ain't easy. These elements are random numbers, not a1, a2. How do I sort them?

Comment: Sorting will help you get all similar lists together.Than `Split` will get them separated and you can pick them using `Part`.

Comment: @Blackbird I can't see how. Could you do it for this example? Thanks.

Comment: @Shb Is the matrix image in the question correct?  It seems to be scaled 4 x 2 instead of 2 x 2.  See the comments to my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can also achieve your ultimate (or ulterior) goal with `ImageResize`:

```
imgdata = Array[0.2 #1 + 0.1 #2 - 0.2 + 0.01 #3 &, {2, 2, 3}]
(* {{{0.11, 0.12, 0.13}, {0.21, 0.22, 0.23}}, {{0.31, 0.32, 0.33}, {0.41, 0.42, 0.43}}} *)

img = Image @ imgdata;
img2 = ImageResize[img, Scaled[2]];

ImageData[img2] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

P.S. There are various [`Resampling`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Resampling.html) algorithms built into *Mathematica*.

Comment: Ha, nice! Why bother killing the bird when you can just order a cooked one at the restaurant... :)

Comment: by the way, you can use the `Scaled` symbol like this: `ImageResize[img, Scaled[2]]`

Comment: @amr Thanks, I should have known.  I guess I hurried too much.  I edited it to include your suggestion - it seems better.

Comment: Wait a minute, this isn't the output shown in the question; it is a 2x2 rather than 2x4 scaling.  This should be `ImageResize[img, {Scaled[4], Scaled[2]}]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  Hmm...the words say "I want to double the resolution", but the matrix image suggests you may be right. I suppose the question needs clarifying.

Answer (score 7):

One of the most direct ways hasn't been shown yet, which is to expand each element at level 2 with e.g. `ConstantArray` and then `ArrayFlatten` the entire result.  *Edit: Actually Nasser did this manually, without `Map` and using the less efficient `Table`, but the idea is identical.*

```
ArrayFlatten @ Map[ConstantArray[#, {2, 4}] &, list1, {2}]
```

[image]

Slightly more complicated but significantly faster is to expand the entire array and then `Flatten` as necessary:

```
ConstantArray[#, {2, 4}] ~Flatten~ {{3, 1}, {4, 2}} & @ list1
```

On my system this tests faster than any other code I have tried, including `ImageResize` (see below).

---

### Timings

Timings for all methods posted so far, in version 7.

*Edit: Michael's ouput does not match the question or other answers.  The code should be `ImageResize[img, {Scaled[4], Scaled[2]}]` which I will use below.*

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]
timeAvg[func_] := Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}]

list1 = RandomInteger[99, {500, 500, 3}];

ArrayFlatten @ Map[ConstantArray[#, {2, 4}] &, list1, {2}]    // timeAvg
ConstantArray[#, {2, 4}] ~Flatten~ {{3, 1}, {4, 2}} & @ list1 // timeAvg

ArrayFlatten[
  Transpose[Outer[Times, {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}, list1], {3, 4, 1, 2}]] // timeAvg

ImageData@ImageResize[Image@list1, {Scaled[4], Scaled[2]}] // timeAvg

Module[{f},
  f[x_] := ArrayFlatten@Table[x, {2}, {4}];
  ArrayFlatten@Map[f, list1, {2}]
] // timeAvg

With[{
   grid = ArrayFlatten[Table[ConstantArray[Slot@n, {2, 4}], {n, 4}]~Partition~2]
   },
  grid & @@ Flatten[list1, 1]
] // timeAvg

With[{exp = {2, 4}},
  Array[
   Extract[list1, Ceiling[{#1, #2}/exp]] &,
   exp Most@Dimensions[list1]
  ]
] // timeAvg
```

> 0.2714
>
> 0.03684
>
> 1.373
>
> 0.0512
>
> 1.529
>
> 0.0686
>
> 6.209

My second function takes first place, Michael's takes second, and rm-rf's takes third.  Note that Michael's is less general, applying only to data that is handled by `Image`.

Answer (score 4):

Observing the pattern in the desired output, you can construct something like this (extensible to larger grids):

```
With[{grid = ArrayFlatten[Table[ConstantArray[Slot@n, {2, 4}], {n, 4}] ~Partition~ 2]},
    grid & @@ Flatten[list, 1] 
] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

`grid` here is a pure function (well, only the slots) that looks like this, mimicking the structure of your output:

[image]

to which we pass the individual sublists as arguments.

Comment: Oh darn, you beat me.

Answer (score 3):

Michael E2's answer may be the best from the point of view of dealing with images, but there is a Mathematica function designed to do this kind of thing, the generalized `Outer` product. Using the definition of `list1` from above,

```
list1 = {{{a1, a2, a3}, {b1, b2, b3}}, {{c1, c2, c3}, {d1, d2, d3}}};
ArrayFlatten[Transpose[Outer[Times, {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}, list1], 
                   {3, 4, 1, 2}]] // MatrixForm
```

[image: array]

The outer product almost gives the desired form, but a `Transpose` is needed followed by an `ArrayFlatten` to remove an extra set of parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Not too automated, but it is only a 2 by 2 matrix looking at the final matrix

```
f[x_] := ArrayFlatten@Table[x, {2}, {4}];
a = {a1, a2, a3};
b = {b1, b2, b3};
c = {c1, c2, c3};
d = {d1, d2, d3};
(mat = {{a, b}, {c, d}}) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ArrayFlatten[{{f[a], f[b]}, {f[c], f[d]}}] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I realize that this is basically my "direct" method (though a bit less optimized), I just didn't recognize it. +1

Answer (score 1):

Here is some "reverse" approach:

```
exp = {2, 4};

Array[
      Extract[list1, Ceiling[{#1, #2}/exp]] &,
      exp Most@Dimensions[list1]
     ]
```

Comment: Couldn't you post that *before* I completed my timings? ;^)  +1 for options, but this is notably slower than other methods.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I was only curious. Not enough possibilities left to compete without stealing. :)

Answer (score 0):

A judicious combination of `Transpose[]` and `KroneckerProduct[]` can do this:

```
Transpose[KroneckerProduct[#, ConstantArray[1, {2, 4}]] & /@ 
          Transpose[list1, {2, 3, 1}], {3, 1, 2}]
```

If you want to use `Flatten[]` instead of `Transpose[]`:

```
Flatten[KroneckerProduct[#, ConstantArray[1, {2, 4}]] & /@ 
        Flatten[l1, {{3}, {1}, {2}}], {{2}, {3}, {1}}]
```